# Case Sensitve NTFS Folder?

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, ntfs, case-sensitive

I am migrating a Linux/Apache/PHP website to a server running Windows Server 2008 R2/IIS 7.0.

I have everything working except one minor issue. The file system on the Linux box is case-sensitive and many of the files will have duplicate filenames on Windows.

How would I go about making the folder C:\Website\Site1 case-sensitive so that I can store all the files on the original server there?

If I have to turn on case-sensitivity for the entire server, so be it.  There is nothing else running on it.

Comment: I think you have it backwards. Linux is case sensitive, windows is not.

Comment: OK, forget NTFS.  I can make a volume with whatever file system I need, so long as Windows Server 2008 supports it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't enable case sensitivity for a single folder or volume on Windows, but you can do it for the whole system.

You need to change the value of the Registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\obcaseinsensitive
```

from 1 to 0 and reboot the system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really answering the OP's question, but an alternative might be to run a script that finds duplicate-named files and folders and renames one of them (maybe add a '~1' on the end of the name).

You may have this file server for a long time (our current one is running for about 7 years now), and you probably won't want to have to deal with this again in a future migration, in case your forget about it, or in case you leave and it causes a headache for a future sysadmin who did not realize this was done (referring to Massimo's answer).

Comment: If the web site contains links (which it very likely does), this is going to break everything.